# Want to check exception or failure reason from sequelize ORM

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, sequelize.js

I want some mechanism in nodeJS (express) that can check for any errors while manipulating a record in MySQL database using sequelize ORM.
for example:

```
sequelize.create({ 
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email })
.then((data)=> { res.send('mysuccess message'); })
.catch( (err) => { 
    if( <unique key is violated> ) { 
        res.send('myerrormessage');
    }
}));
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sequelize provide error classes that you can check in your catch block

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/errors/index.js~UniqueConstraintError.html

```
sequelize.create({ 
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email })
.then((data)=> { res.send('mysuccess message'); })
.catch(Sequelize.UniqueConstraintError => {  
    res.send('myerrormessage');
}));
```

If you want to use the try...catch version, you cannot cumulate the catch blocks, so you might want to check with

```
if (err instanceof Sequelize.UniqueConstraintError)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

> `sequelize.query` is used by all queries in `sequelize`, so perhaps
>   you could overwrite that and attach an error handler:
>
> ```
> Sequelize.prototype.query = function () {
>   return originalQuery.apply(this, arguments).catch(function (err) {
>     // log the error 
>
>     throw err;
>   });
> };
> ```

For more detail : **[DO READ](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1707)**